# rspec mocking out ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing some rspec tests and I notice that it slows down when accessing my Mailer class. Is there a way to mock out the ActionMailer::Base class completely so I can test other components of my controller before and after the email delivery?

Here is my mailer class definition

```
class OrganisationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
# code to send emails
end
```

Here is one of the tests I've written

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe OrganisationsController do

  describe "#email_single" do
    context "With email address" do 
      let(:org) {Organisation.make!}

      it "redirects to listing" do
        get :email_single, :id => org.id
        response.should redirect_to(organisations_path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to answer with the little snippet you've included, but you should be able to stub out whatever messages your controller sends to `OrganisationMailer` so that they are no-ops in the rspec examples where you don't care to exercise that logic.

Alternately, you can look at replacing `OrganisationMailer` with a test double using `stub_const`:

```
stub_const("OrganisationMailer", my_test_double)
```

Then you can completely control the interaction between the controller and the mailer.